# No enable wifi option after installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, broadcom

Clicking on the wifi dropdown menu on the upper right shows options of "Ethernet Network"(greyed out) and "Enable Networking". However there is no enable Wifi option at all. Running `sudo service network-manager restart` doesn't fix the issue, just prompts the "Disconnnected-you are now offline" popup.

Running `lspci -nn -d 14e4:` returns `06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless Lan Controller [14e4:432b] (rev01)`

Hardware switch for wifi on the laptop (which is a lightup button) is continuously lit up meaning that wifi should be on, except it's not.

Not sure what to do, but thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Try connecting to the Internet over wired network, then start "Additional Drivers" and see if Ubuntu finds a proprietary driver for your Wifi controller automatically. If it does, try switching to the proprietary driver.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello,**

I had this problem on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Try disabling secure boot in BIOS.
It worked for me.

Hope I helped,

**-orion-**